# How to check if the bitmap has data?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

**What I have:** I am downloading an image from a URL and converting it to a bitmap.

**What is happening:** Sometimes the server returns an image, other times just a small placeholder.

**What I am trying to do:** How to find out if the bitmap contains an image (the image is quite medium sized compared to the placeholder which is tiny).

**Code used to get the image from the URL:**

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do mention that the placeholder is smaller than a typical image. Is it enough to measure the width/height of the bitmap to distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Determinate minimum width and height of image and if bitmap height and width is smaller than this minimum, it means that is placeholder. For example

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(f);
int minHeight = 500;
int minWidth = 500;
if(bitmap.getHeight() < minHeight && bitmap.getWidth() < minWidth){
//it is a placeholder
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the placeholder is the same size every time then just replace 60 with it's height in pixels.  This just takes a `Bitmap` and returns `true` if the `Bitmap` height matches your placeholder.

```
private bool isPlaceholder (Bitmap bmp)
{
    //presumably, the placeholder never changes size
    //if it's 60 then we've got a placeholder
    if (bmp.Height == 60){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This only works if the placeholder is *always* smaller than the image.  Otherwise you would perhaps need more complex logic like checking the height *and* size of the image in bytes.  OR Height and Width.  If it's always smaller in height then you can use something like above.